# Why is rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)) not the same as Reduce(rbind,c(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))?

Tags: r, reduce, rbind

Lets say I want to rbind an arbitrary number of objects of the same length, so I thought reducing a vector of that objects is the solution. But:

```
rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
>     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    4    5    6
```

However,

```
Reduce(rbind,c(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))
>      [,1]
 init     1
          2
          3
          4
          5
          6
```

Why don't the two produce the same output and how do should I rbind an arbitray number of objects of the same length?

Comment: Use `do.call(rbind,list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))` or pass the arguments to Reduce as a list `Reduce(rbind,list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run just

```
c(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

you'll see that's it's just creating a single vector of length 6. It's not two separate vectors. You can't have a vector that contains other vectors, but you can have a list that contains vectors. Therefor, the correct syntax is

```
Reduce(rbind,list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# init    1    2    3
#         4    5    6
```

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary number of vectors, you can put them into a `list` and use `do.call`

```
> do.call("rbind", list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    4    5    6
```

On a longer list, for example:

```
> do.call("rbind", list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6), 7:9, 10:12))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    4    5    6
#[3,]    7    8    9
#[4,]   10   11   12
```